# How do you force a screen refresh in GTK 3.8?

Tags: c, gtk3

Found a solution. See below.

I am using GTK 3.8 **gtk_grid** in a scrolled window. The C code works through a lot of data and displays some in the grid. GTK does not draw the grid until the program finishes processing all data. How do you force GTK 3 to refresh the screen when you add data?

I tried **gtk_widget_queue_draw** but nothing happens.
I also tested **gtk_widget_show_now** but nothing happened.

The process might run for a few seconds or many minutes. The user can select the range of data to display and the refresh. The refresh might be every 5 seconds or every 10 rows. I would be happy if either worked.

The only relevant question I can find is on GTK 2 and recommends gtk_widget_queue_draw which does not work. I read all the GTK documentation and that recommends the same function. Something is missing in the documentation, examples, and answers.

From what I can see, I would have to process 100 rows then stop and display a button to request the next 100. This is not viable. The user needs the data scrolling through to the end.

GTK_grid appears to have changed a few times in version 3. I am not locked into GTK_grid if there is a more efficient or effective way to display rows and columns. There is no option to revert to an earlier GTK.

---

I found something that works in GTK 3.8. Add a line after gtk_widget_queue_draw:

```
gtk_widget_queue_draw(results);  
while (g_main_context_pending(NULL)) {
    g_main_context_iteration(NULL,FALSE);
}
```

Read [The Main Event Loop](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html) for more details.

Comment: I think you need to post some code as the answer could be in your event handling [particularly for expose events]. If you're doing heavy computation, you may be starving the event handler. You might also consider splitting computation off into a separate thread so the main thread is free to handle all GTK related activity.

Comment: Hello Craig, the processing is way less than the available power. The wait is on the SSD. The code has plenty of time to redraw. When I added the funny extra code for GTK, the redraw screamed along even with a redraw on every row.

Comment: What I cannot find is an option to close the question.

Comment: The `g_main_context_*` you just posted will work (i.e. events as I had mentioned). The thread split I suggested wasn't for speed reasons, but as a way to get smooth event processing without having to interject the `g_main_context_*` calls in various/numerous places. No need to close the question, you're fine. Just add a one liner at the top, indicating you found the solution: (e.g. "found a solution, see below"). That's easier for others to see. I would reformat the solution in an indented code block, however. You're also free to post your solution as a real answer just like somebody else

Comment: Can you please provide minimum code to reproduce?

Comment: @KyryloPolezhaiev OP has already posted the solution at the bottom of the [edited] question

Comment: @Kyrylo, I do not know what the minimum useful code could be. You can only see the problem when the code runs for a while. I get the problem because I read thousands of rows and and display some throughout the process. The example would have to have loops displaying data and loops chewing up some time between each display.

Comment: A hint for anyone looking at gtk_grid: It is slow for anything over a few hundred lines.

Comment: The problem and solotion are the same in GTK 3.22.