# How to switch GTK CSS style_context mid-run

Tags: c++, gtk

### Description of Problem

I would like to switch the `style_context` of a button once my program switches from state A to state B.  I initialize my GTK instance as an `app` which includes the lines:

```
provider = gtk_css_provider_new();
gtk_css_provider_load_from_data (provider, gtk_class::css_string.c_str(), -1, NULL);
gtk_style_context_add_provider(gtk_widget_get_style_context(mybutton), 
    GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER(myprovider), 
    GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_USER);
```

This gives `mybutton` the default style.  When I switch program states, I want to black out this button.  Therefore, I prepared a class in the css stylesheet called `hidebutton`.  However, when I try calling:

```
gtk_style_context_remove_provider(
    gtk_widget_get_style_context(mybutton), 
    GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER(provider));
gtk_style_context_add_class(
    gtk_widget_get_style_context (mybutton), 
    "hidebutton");
gtk_style_context_add_provider(gtk_widget_get_style_context(mybutton), 
    GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER(provider), 
    GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_USER);
```

nothing seems to happen.

### Fix attempts

In one attempt to fix this, I tried forcing a redraw with:

```
GdkScreen *screen = gdk_screen_get_default();
gtk_style_context_reset_widgets(screen);
```

In another attempt, I tried a force redraw with the method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34912757/how-do-you-force-a-screen-refresh-in-gtk-3-8).

### What am I missing?

I feel like I'm probably missing something obvious, but my code is getting so complicated that I can't see it.

### Reference Material

My CSS info:

```
std::string get_css_string() {
    screen_size();
    std::string css_string;
    std::cout << "width: " << WORK_WIDTH << std::endl;
    std::cout << "height: " << WORK_HEIGHT << std::endl;
    std::cout << "font-size: " << ((WORK_WIDTH*20)/WORK_HEIGHT) << std::endl;
    std::string font_size_string = std::to_string((WORK_WIDTH*20)/WORK_HEIGHT);
    css_string = "window { background-color: black; \
         color: red; \
         font-size: " + font_size_string + "px; \
         font-weight: bolder; } \
         button { background-image: image(dimgray); \
         border-color: dimgray; \
         text-shadow: 0 1px black; \
         color: red; \
         font-size: " + font_size_string + "px; \
         font-weight: bolder; } \
         .hidebutton {background-image: image(black); \
         color: black; \
         border-width: 0px; \
         border-color: black; } \
         .shadowbutton {background-image: image(dimgray); \
         color: darkgray; \
         font-size: " + font_size_string + "px; \
         font-weight: bolder; \
         border-width: 0px; \
         border-color: black; }";
    return css_string;
}
```

and later initialized with

```
gtk_css_provider_load_from_data (provider, gtk_class::css_string.c_str(), -1, NULL);
```

Full code, in all it's messy glory, is available on request.  I'm not going to post it all here, since it is a tangle of `mmap` variables across multiple `fork`s.

Answer (score 1):

As I see in examples, you are doing it in the wrong order, in GTK+ [docs](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-migrating-GtkStyleContext-checklist.html) you can see this:

```
GtkStyleContext *context;
context = gtk_widget_get_style_context (widget);
gtk_style_context_save (context);
gtk_style_context_add_class (context, "your_css_class");
// render widget
gtk_style_context_remove_class (context, "your_css_class");
```

You don't need to remove the provider.

A note:

> Replace all gtk_paint_*() calls with corresponding gtk_render_*() calls

And in your css you don't have any `.hidebutton` class.

This is an example of `css`:

```
context = gtk_widget_get_style_context (ebox);
    provider = (GtkStyleProvider *)gtk_css_provider_new ();
    gtk_css_provider_load_from_data (GTK_CSS_PROVIDER (provider),
                                      ".frame1 {\n"
                                      "   border-image: url('gradient1.png') 10 10 10 10 stretch;\n"
                                      "}\n"
                                      ".frame2 {\n"
                                      "   border-style: solid;\n"
                                      "   border-color: rgb(255,0,0);\n"
                                      "   border-width: 10;\n"
                                      "   border-radius: 10;\n"
                                      "}\n"
                                      ".frame3 {\n"
                                      "   border-style: solid;\n"
                                      "   border-color: rgb(0,0,0);\n"
                                      "   border-width: 2;\n"
                                      "   border-radius: 10;\n"
                                      "}\n"
                                      ".background {\n"
                                      "   border-radius: 10;\n"
                                      "   border-width: 0;\n"
                                      "   background-image: -gtk-gradient (linear, left top, right bottom, from(#ff00ff), to(#aabbcc));\n"
                                      "}\n"
                                      ".frame {\n"
                                      "   border-style: solid;\n"
                                      "   border-width: 1;\n"
                                      "   border-radius: 0;\n"
                                      "}\n", -1, NULL);
     gtk_style_context_add_provider (context, provider, GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION);
```

Comment: I updated the OP to correct some things you pointed out (I changed ``fakebutton`` in the CSS to match the variable in my example ``hidebutton`` and added more lines to the first snippet).  Does this change your assessment?

Comment: @WesH not about the order of instructions and about removing the provider.

Comment: I tested running with the order and non-removal you suggested, and the screen appears the same.  When I print the ``GList`` of attributes for the context before and after the state change, the original entry remains and a second entry appears.  This makes it appear as if the original CSS context did not get removed properly.

Comment: I can successfully remove the class.  I created an MWE (https://gist.github.com/BlueNalgene/8fece854483a4257b838751999e01c38) which switches the class without issue.  However, in my original and more complicated program (https://github.com/BlueNalgene/LunAero_C/commit/06f798e15166f889a3feae6834dcbb6895187b71) the print function reports the correct class reassignment, but nothing changes in the GUI.

Comment: @WesH try `gtk_widget_queue_draw` on the widget or window context.

Comment: @WesH you may try some simpler `css` to see if there are changes. Or force the redraw externally by obscuring part of the widget with another application to see if the problem comes from events being blocked waiting and no redraw occurs until there is a queue movement.

Comment: @WesH also, in your working github example you is adding a provider to the widget `gtk_style_context_add_provider(gtk_widget_get_style_context(button))` but in the real code don't. [Docs](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/chap-css-overview.html) are unclear for me, but may be you need to add the provider to each widget.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  A combination of your cleanup suggestions, the while loop suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34912757/how-do-you-force-a-screen-refresh-in-gtk-3-8), and some ``semaphore`` problems found elsewhere in the code, I was able to get this working.  This wasn't a great question since there were so many factors, I apologize.